# Difference between "be tagged as" or "be labelled as"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What's the difference between 'be tagged (as)' and 'be labelled (as)'?
For example
"The country no longer wanted to ____ as a Third World nation".
Which terms could I use to fill in the blank?

Comment: Here the idiom is "be labelled", but as with most idioms, I don't think there's any logical reason for it.  The verbs "to tag" something and "to label" something are similar in meaning, but used in different ways.  In the dictionary, "to tag" is literally defined as "to attach a label to"

Answer (score 1):

I would say "be labelled (as)," although as a native speaker I would still understand the meaning if I heard "be tagged (as)," although I would find it a big peculiar. I think of tagging as what happens when you're "tagged" in a Facebook photo.